# vim: How to jump to the start of a function when "{" is not in the first column

Tags: vim

In vim, if "{" is not in the first column,how to jump to the start of a function? Language is C. I try `[[`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[m`

Read:

> [m
>   Go to [count] previous start of a method (for Java or           similar
>   structured language).  When not after the             start of a method, jump
>   to the start or end of the            class.  When no '{' is found before the
>   cursor this is            an error. |exclusive| motion. {not in Vi}

### update

```
If your '{' or '}' are not in the first column, and you would like to use "[["
and "]]" anyway, try these mappings: >
   :map [[ ?{<CR>w99[{
   :map ][ /}<CR>b99]}
   :map ]] j0[[%/{<CR>
   :map [] k$][%?}<CR>
```

Comment: I've tried, but it doesn't. Language is C. It just jumps to every "{"(`if` block as well), not the start of a function.

Comment: @user7328234, read the docs to get a more detailed explanation. In the insert mode type `:h [m`. I'm mentioning this just in case you ain't accustomed to look into vim's docs, as I used to be

Answer (score 0):

In [lh-cpp](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp) I override `]m` to jump only at start of function definitions (in C++, and C as well). It's based on lh-dev feature I've demonstrated over [vi.SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7942/626).

Note, however that while your situation is quite common in C++, I've never encountered it in C. Is there any good reason to not have C functions defined in first column?

Comment: I'm reading an open source project written in C. The "{" is in the end of the first line of a function.